# Selenium doesn't give updated AJAX content

Tags: ajax, selenium, dom, web-crawler

I want to get table contents from this website: "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2". When 
I Inspect Element, on Chrome browser, I can find the table entries in the DOMTree as displayed in the browser. But when I run the following code, I get a different table which corresponds to the table in https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

BASEURL = "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/manpreet/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2")

##for i in range(5000):
##    print i
##    time.sleep(1)
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table'))
    )
finally:
    print('10 secs over')

print(elem.text)
```

I called the WebDriverWait function for upto 30 seconds but I don't get the correct table. I noticed that when I use WebDriverWait, the browser opened by Selenium displays the table in https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card for the entire duration of 30 seconds. But when I don't use WebDriverWait, the driver first displays the table in https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card, the page loads for a few seconds and then displays the table in https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2. The whole process only takes about 5-6 seconds (at most). I think the Ajax call is getting stuck when I use WebDriverWait. And this might be the reason selenium doesn't return the correct table because Selenium scrapes the displayed content.

Can anybody tell me how to get the correct table?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think WebDriverWait could interrupt the page loading.

A point to be noted in here is that even if you are trying to *get* the url https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2 (say page#2) directly, the application first loads the full list as in https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card (say page#1) and then pass the query parameters to the filters (Club and Season).

Now the problem is, there is an element which satisfies your element locator 
*EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table'))* in page#1 itself. (ie. in url https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card), so selenium already got its element and hence you are seeing the text from the page#1 and not page#2.

What you could do:

** You could ask Python to sleep for sometime after the *get* method call using, so that before you try to locate the element, the actual page (page#2) might get loaded

```
...
driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2")
time.sleep(3)
try:
   ...
```

** Just before the application redirects to page#2, you could observe that the filter values are set in the page and a loader div appears and disappears. You could wait till the loader appears and disappears. Below code worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time

# wait for the loading to be complete
def waitFn(): 
    for x in range(4):
        try:
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.loader-small'))
            )
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.loader-small'))
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            continue

BASEURL = "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2")
delay = 3 # seconds

##for i in range(5000):
##    print i
# time.sleep(5)

waitFn()

try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table'))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"

finally:
    print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need more waits.

1.Wait until the stat drop down is close. You can wait for css style 'transform' value to be changed. See the custom wait, `element_transform_changed`, in my answer.
2.Wait until all filters have been displayed. Just use `WebDriverWait` with `EC`.
3.Sleep for several seconds to wait for Javascript execution. Use `time.sleep()`.

```
BASEURL = "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/red_card?se=42&cl=2")

##for i in range(5000):
##    print i
##    time.sleep(1)

class element_transform_changed(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(self.locator))
        newText = element.value_of_css_property("transform")
        if newText is None or len(newText)==0:
            return False

        print("OLD: " + self.text + ", NEW: " + newText)

        if len(self.text)==0 or (self.text!=newText.strip()):
            return element
        else:
            return False

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(element_transform_changed((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-script='pl_stats'] [class*='topStatsFilterDropdown'] ul"),"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-dropdown-current='FOOTBALL_COMPSEASON']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-dropdown-current='FOOTBALL_CLUB']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-dropdown-current='Nationality']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-dropdown-current='Position']")))
    time.sleep(5)
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table')))
except:
    print('ERROR')

print(elem.text)
time.sleep(10)
```